How to reset Jenkins workspace path
After aborting a pipeline Jenkins changed the workspace from opt/jenkins/workspace/some-project to opt/jenkins/workspace/some-project@2.
This is not a problem for the execution of another build, however, it causes issues with outside integrations (CI Visibility) that we have set up for this pipeline.
Is there a way to reset the workspace?
I tried deleting the workspace directories from the worker but it didin't help. This is stored somewhere in Jenkins. I searched for some locks or tmp files but I couldn't find anything.
I'd appreciate your help.

You don't reset a workspace path in Jenkins. The @2, @3 and other directories just represent different workspaces for different builds of the same pipeline - typically it happens when they are being built simultaneously, and it's absolutely expected since you don't want them to rewrite each others workspaces.
You can probably use the customWorkspace parameter of agent section, but to make it really immutable you'll need to use absolute paths:

Run the Pipeline or individual stage this agent is applied to within this custom workspace, rather than the default. It can be either a relative path, in which case the custom workspace will be under the workspace root on the node, or an absolute path.

But with this you will likely have to disable the ability to run the builds simultaneously with disableConcurrent option:

Disallow concurrent executions of the Pipeline. Can be useful for preventing simultaneous accesses to shared resources, etc. For example: options { disableConcurrentBuilds() } to queue a build when there’s already an executing build of the Pipeline, or options { disableConcurrentBuilds(abortPrevious: true) } to abort the running one and start the new build.

